# easy solution needed to subset spectra files in list.files

Tags: r, list

I have a folder full of spectra files. The number of files can vary with different measurements as well as the repetitions.
I have so far and it works:

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "^Q\\d+")
print(files)
```

and `print(list)` gives:

> ```
> [1] "Q010101N.001" "Q010101N.002" "Q010101N.003" "Q010101N.004" "Q010101N.005" "Q010101N.006"
>   [7] "Q010101N.007" "Q010101N.008" "Q010101N.009" "Q010101N.010" "Q010101N.011" "Q010101N.012"
>  [13] "Q010101N.013" "Q010101N.014" "Q010101N.015" "Q010101N.016" "Q010101N.017" "Q010101N.018"
>  [19] "Q010101N.019" "Q010101N.020" "Q010101N.021" "Q010101N.022" "Q010101N.023" "Q010101N.024"
>  [25] "Q010101N.025" "Q021101N.001" "Q021101N.002" "Q021101N.003" "Q021101N.004" "Q021101N.005"
>  [31] "Q021101N.006" "Q021101N.007" "Q021101N.008" "Q021101N.009" "Q021101N.010" "Q021101N.011"
>  [37] "Q021101N.012" "Q021101N.013" "Q021101N.014" "Q021101N.015" "Q021101N.016" "Q021101N.017"
>  [43] "Q021101N.018" "Q021101N.019" "Q021101N.020" "Q021101N.021" "Q021101N.022" "Q021101N.023"
>  [49] "Q021101N.024" "Q021101N.025" "Q031201N.001" "Q031201N.002" "Q031201N.003" "Q031201N.004"
>  [55] "Q031201N.005" "Q031201N.006" "Q031201N.007" "Q031201N.008" "Q031201N.009" "Q031201N.010"
>  [61] "Q031201N.011" "Q031201N.012" "Q031201N.013" "Q031201N.014" "Q031201N.015" "Q031201N.016"
>  [67] "Q031201N.017" "Q031201N.018" "Q031201N.019" "Q031201N.020" "Q031201N.021" "Q031201N.022"
>  [73] "Q031201N.023" "Q031201N.024" "Q031201N.025" "Q041301N.001" "Q041301N.002" "Q041301N.003"
>  [79] "Q041301N.004" "Q041301N.005" "Q041301N.006" "Q041301N.007" "Q041301N.008" "Q041301N.009"
>  [85] "Q041301N.010" "Q041301N.011" "Q041301N.012" "Q041301N.013" "Q041301N.014" "Q041301N.015"
>  [91] "Q041301N.016" "Q041301N.017" "Q041301N.018" "Q041301N.019" "Q041301N.020" "Q041301N.021"
>  [97] "Q041301N.022" "Q041301N.023" "Q041301N.024" "Q041301N.025" "Q051401N.001" "Q051401N.002"
> [103] "Q051401N.003" "Q051401N.004" "Q051401N.005" "Q051401N.006" "Q051401N.007" "Q051401N.008"
> [109] "Q051401N.009" "Q051401N.010" "Q051401N.011" "Q051401N.012" "Q051401N.013" "Q051401N.014"
> [115] "Q051401N.015" "Q051401N.016" "Q051401N.017" "Q051401N.018" "Q051401N.019" "Q051401N.020"
> [121] "Q051401N.021" "Q051401N.022" "Q051401N.023" "Q051401N.024" "Q051401N.025" "Q061501N.001"
> [127] "Q061501N.002" "Q061501N.003" "Q061501N.004" "Q061501N.005" "Q061501N.006" "Q061501N.007"
> [133] "Q061501N.008" "Q061501N.009" "Q061501N.010" "Q061501N.011" "Q061501N.012" "Q061501N.013"
> [139] "Q061501N.014" "Q061501N.015" "Q061501N.016" "Q061501N.017" "Q061501N.018" "Q061501N.019"
> [145] "Q061501N.020" "Q061501N.021" "Q061501N.022" "Q061501N.023" "Q061501N.024" "Q061501N.025"
> [151] "Q071601N.001" "Q071601N.002" "Q071601N.003" "Q071601N.004" "Q071601N.005" "Q071601N.006"
> [157] "Q071601N.007" "Q071601N.008" "Q071601N.009" "Q071601N.010" "Q071601N.011" "Q071601N.012"
> [163] "Q071601N.013" "Q071601N.014" "Q071601N.015" "Q071601N.016" "Q071601N.017" "Q071601N.018"
> [169] "Q071601N.019" "Q071601N.020" "Q071601N.021" "Q071601N.022" "Q071601N.023" "Q071601N.024"
> [175] "Q071601N.025" "Q081701N.001" "Q081701N.002" "Q081701N.003" "Q081701N.004" "Q081701N.005"
> [181] "Q081701N.006" "Q081701N.007" "Q081701N.008" "Q081701N.009" "Q081701N.010" "Q081701N.011"
> [187] "Q081701N.012" "Q081701N.013" "Q081701N.014" "Q081701N.015" "Q081701N.016" "Q081701N.017"
> [193] "Q081701N.018" "Q081701N.019" "Q081701N.020" "Q081701N.021" "Q081701N.022" "Q081701N.023"
> [199] "Q081701N.024" "Q081701N.025" "Q091801N.001" "Q091801N.002" "Q091801N.003" "Q091801N.004"
> [205] "Q091801N.005" "Q091801N.006" "Q091801N.007" "Q091801N.008" "Q091801N.009" "Q091801N.010"
> [211] "Q091801N.011" "Q091801N.012" "Q091801N.013" "Q091801N.014" "Q091801N.015" "Q091801N.016"
> [217] "Q091801N.017" "Q091801N.018" "Q091801N.019" "Q091801N.020" "Q091801N.021" "Q091801N.022"
> [223] "Q091801N.023" "Q091801N.024" "Q091801N.025" "Q101901N.001" "Q101901N.002" "Q101901N.003"
> [229] "Q101901N.004" "Q101901N.005" "Q101901N.006" "Q101901N.007" "Q101901N.008" "Q101901N.009"
> [235] "Q101901N.010" "Q101901N.011" "Q101901N.012" "Q101901N.013" "Q101901N.014" "Q101901N.015"
> [241] "Q101901N.016" "Q101901N.017" "Q101901N.018" "Q101901N.019" "Q101901N.020" "Q101901N.021"
> [247] "Q101901N.022" "Q101901N.023" "Q101901N.024" "Q101901N.025" "Q112001N.001" "Q112001N.002"
> [253] "Q112001N.003" "Q112001N.004" "Q112001N.005" "Q112001N.006" "Q112001N.007" "Q112001N.008"
> [259] "Q112001N.009" "Q112001N.010" "Q112001N.011" "Q112001N.012" "Q112001N.013" "Q112001N.014"
> [265] "Q112001N.015" "Q112001N.016" "Q112001N.017" "Q112001N.018" "Q112001N.019" "Q112001N.020"
> [271] "Q112001N.021" "Q112001N.022" "Q112001N.023" "Q112001N.024" "Q112001N.025" "Q124101N.001"
> [277] "Q124101N.002" "Q124101N.003" "Q124101N.004" "Q124101N.005" "Q124101N.006" "Q124101N.007"
> [283] "Q124101N.008" "Q124101N.009" "Q124101N.010" "Q124101N.011" "Q124101N.012" "Q124101N.013"
> [289] "Q124101N.014" "Q124101N.015" "Q124101N.016" "Q124101N.017" "Q124101N.018" "Q124101N.019"
> [295] "Q124101N.020" "Q124101N.021" "Q124101N.022" "Q124101N.023" "Q124101N.024" "Q124101N.025"
> [301] "Q134201N.001" "Q134201N.002" "Q134201N.003" "Q134201N.004" "Q134201N.005" "Q134201N.006"
> [307] "Q134201N.007" "Q134201N.008" "Q134201N.009" "Q134201N.010" "Q134201N.011" "Q134201N.012"
> [313] "Q134201N.013" "Q134201N.014" "Q134201N.015" "Q134201N.016" "Q134201N.017" "Q134201N.018"
> [319] "Q134201N.019" "Q134201N.020" "Q134201N.021" "Q134201N.022" "Q134201N.023" "Q134201N.024"
> [325] "Q134201N.025" "Q144301N.001" "Q144301N.002" "Q144301N.003" "Q144301N.004" "Q144301N.005"
> [331] "Q144301N.006" "Q144301N.007" "Q144301N.008" "Q144301N.009" "Q144301N.010" "Q144301N.011"
> [337] "Q144301N.012" "Q144301N.013" "Q144301N.014" "Q144301N.015" "Q144301N.016" "Q144301N.017"
> [343] "Q144301N.018" "Q144301N.019" "Q144301N.020" "Q144301N.021" "Q144301N.022" "Q144301N.023"
> [349] "Q144301N.024" "Q144301N.025" "Q154401N.001" "Q154401N.002" "Q154401N.003" "Q154401N.004"
> [355] "Q154401N.005" "Q154401N.006" "Q154401N.007" "Q154401N.008" "Q154401N.009" "Q154401N.010"
> [361] "Q154401N.011" "Q154401N.012" "Q154401N.013" "Q154401N.014" "Q154401N.015" "Q154401N.016"
> [367] "Q154401N.017" "Q154401N.018" "Q154401N.019" "Q154401N.020" "Q154401N.021" "Q154401N.022"
> [373] "Q154401N.023" "Q154401N.024" "Q154401N.025" "Q164501N.001" "Q164501N.002" "Q164501N.003"
> [379] "Q164501N.004" "Q164501N.005" "Q164501N.006" "Q164501N.007" "Q164501N.008" "Q164501N.009"
> [385] "Q164501N.010" "Q164501N.011" "Q164501N.012" "Q164501N.013" "Q164501N.014" "Q164501N.015"
> [391] "Q164501N.016" "Q164501N.017" "Q164501N.018" "Q164501N.019" "Q164501N.020" "Q164501N.021"
> [397] "Q164501N.022" "Q164501N.023" "Q164501N.024" "Q164501N.025" "Q174601N.001" "Q174601N.002"
> [403] "Q174601N.003" "Q174601N.004" "Q174601N.005" "Q174601N.006" "Q174601N.007" "Q174601N.008"
> [409] "Q174601N.009" "Q174601N.010" "Q174601N.011" "Q174601N.012" "Q174601N.013" "Q174601N.014"
> [415] "Q174601N.015" "Q174601N.016" "Q174601N.017" "Q174601N.018" "Q174601N.019" "Q174601N.020"
> [421] "Q174601N.021" "Q174601N.022" "Q174601N.023" "Q174601N.024" "Q174601N.025"
> ```

So in this case I get 425 spectra files and there are 25 repetitions of each sample. However the total number of files could be different another time and it could also be that one sample has 10 repetitions and the rest has 14 for example.
So I would like to subset each sample (with its repetitions into one subset). In this case I would get 17 subsets.
And the I need to import the files, which I have done succesfully before with all spectra files:

```
list.data <- list()

#import all spectra files
 for (i in 1:length(files))
    list.data[[i]] <- read.csv(files[i])
```

Given that I have now subsets, that would be slightly different!?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via a helper function and iteration.  I used `dplyr`, `purrr` and `stringi`. This will put all your files into a single dataframe.  After that you can manipulate it as you see fit.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringi)

read_spectra <- function(file){

  file_name <- basename(file)

  read.csv(file) %>% 
    mutate(sample = stri_extract_first_regex(file_name, "([A-Z][0-9]+)(?=.)"),
           repetition = stri_extract_first_regex(file_name, "(?<=\\.)(\\d+)")) %>%
    select(sample, repetition, everything())

}

full_data <- map_df(files, read_spectra)
```

The helper function:

1. Takes a file from `list.files`.
2. Reads the csv.
3. Uses mutate to make two new columns using regex to extract the sample number and repetition.
4. Orders the columns into sample, repetition and everything else.

The iteration is using `map_df()` from `purrr` to iterate `read_spectra` over each file in `files` and bind all of this together into a dataframe.

Comment: `@JakeKaup` This is a good idea. However, I'd like to separate all the samples and then manipulate them separately. Just because as soon as they are all in one dataframe there is now way for me to distinguish which set belongs to which sample. Or would it be easier to read all the files in together and then subset them?

Comment: You'd be able to track set and sample through the `sample` and `repetition` variables, should you not?  Each row from each file would have those variables.  You can then `split` the dataframe or use list columns in a [`tibble`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tibble/vignettes/tibble.html) to separate the data accordingly

Comment: `@JakeKaup` the problem is that the sample number (via the sample position) and repetition are only mentioned in the file name.

Comment: That's an easy fix, which I've added to my answer.

Comment: `@JakeKaup` this worked perfectly. now it comes up with: `There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)` and when I type in `warnings()` then they are all `1: In bind_rows_(x, .id) : Unequal factor levels: coercing to character
2: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
  binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector`. Is there a way to address it or at least suppress the warnings?